# grepping particular words

Tags: linux, grep

Here is my output from command (`egrep -i '** pid|material|behavior=m' test.inc`)

the output is;

```
PID1:aaa1
MATERIAL1:sss1
PID2:aaa2
MATERIAL2:sss2
PID3:aaa3
MATERIAL3:sss3
CONNECTOR SECTION, ELIMINATION=NO, ELSET=P19933026;SPW_NF-19933026, BEHAVIOR=M19933000;xxxxxxxx_xxx
```

and i wish output has to be;

```
PID1:aaa1
MATERIAL1:sss1
PID2:aaa2
MATERIAL2:sss2
PID3:aaa3
MATERIAL3:sss3
BEHAVIOR=M19933000;xxxxxxxx_xxx
```

Comment: post a testable fragment of your `test.inc` file before grepping

Comment: file contents are like output....every output is content of individual line...

Comment: so, there's no `pid|material` in your output. I'm asking about the initial content because I see your double grep as redundant

Comment: Check my edited POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
egrep -io '(pid|material|behavior=m).*' test.inc
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
echo 'CONNECTOR SECTION, ELIMINATION=NO, ELSET=P19933026;SPW_NF-19933026, BEHAVIOR=M19933000;xxxxxxxx_xxx' | 
grep -o 'BEHAVIOR=.*'
```

Or using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
grep -o 'BEHAVIOR=.*' <<< 'CONNECTOR SECTION, ELIMINATION=NO, ELSET=P19933026;SPW_NF-19933026, BEHAVIOR=M19933000;xxxxxxxx_xxx'
```

### Edit :

you are unclear, but if I understand what you'd like :

```
egrep -i '** pid|material' | sed -r 's/.*(BEHAVIOR=.*)/\1/'
```

Comment: `grep -o '...' <<< "CONNECTOR..."` so your suggestion shows before the string

Comment: @fedorqui OP doesn't mention using bash, so my version is more compliant with other shells

Comment: Oh, that's a good catch. I assumed a here string was part of any shell, not only Bash.

Comment: Added bash bersion

Comment: `egrep -i "pid|material" | grep -io 'BEHAVIOR=.*`

Comment: I have tried this option before posting....doesn't work fully.....this outputs only BEHAVIOR=M19933000;xxxxxxxx_xxx

Comment: the output has to be; 
PID1:aaa1
MATERIAL1:sss1
PID2:aaa2
MATERIAL2:sss2
PID3:aaa3
MATERIAL3:sss3
BEHAVIOR=M19933000;xxxxxxxx_xxx

Comment: @Nayak Where do all the `PID` and `MATERIAL` come from?  Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/423791/edit) to show the full input and required output.